# Как сделать ввод чисел с плавающей точкой с кнопок?(калькулятор)

Tags: ios, xcode, objective-c

Обычное число можно представить вида x=x*10 *y где x -это первая вводимая нами цифра, y-следующая вводимая нами цифра
То есть, в коде (код представлен на Objective C)

```
-(IBACtion) digit:(id)sender {
```

self.number = number*10 + sender.tag;
}

> Получается довольно просто в одну строку
> Но как осуществить набор числа с плавающей точкой (как в стандартных калькуляторах)? Например, ввести 10,54 или 10,678

Comment: Вероятно для получения дробного числа нужно применить деление, но перед этим все равно нужно ввести знак разделителя(точку или запятую)

Comment: Добавьте больше информации. Какой у Вас подход к решению данной проблемы? Добавьте больше кода.